# Why FinancialDerivative fails for the Spread case?

Tags: finance

According to the documentation center for `FinancialDerivative` in version 10.4, when there are multi assets, we still may use `FinancialDerivative` with the corresponding correlation matrix to find the value of a basket option. Here, I try to use it for two assets with the help of `Spread` as follows:

```
FinancialDerivative[{"Spread", "American", 
  "Put"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 50., 
  "Expiration" -> 1.}, {"CurrentPrice" -> {50., 50.}, "Dividend" -> 0,
   "Volatility" -> {0.3, 0.2}, "CorrelationMatrix" -> {0.6}, 
  "InterestRate" -> 0.05}]
```

Here comes two problems. First, there is no way according to the documentation center to write the weights on the assets ($w_1=0.7$ and $w_2=0.3$). I think `FinancialDerivative` automatically considers the weights to be $w_1=0.5$ and $w_2=0.5$ which are not true for my example. Furthermore, the resulting value is incorrect! The true value should be around 3.97, and not the same to the strike price!

I will be grateful if someone give me some tips to handle this issue.

Comment: Do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: Depending on how weight affects your final payoff could you scale your strikes and current prices by the weight?